# What is chrome.googleechotest.com?

Tags: google, chrome

I use chrome (dev channel) on mac osx lion and every now and then it tries to access chrome.googleechotest.com on port 80 (EDIT: and other ports!).

Anybody knows what is the deal with chrome.googleechotest.com ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like its an google's echo test for chrome.  The whois (below) points back to Google, Inc.  It seems that it is used to send back [network connectivity stats to a google server for ~0.5% of users.](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=git/chromium.git;a=commitdiff;h=5151531d9366a1f7bb16c2cd26471db794acce24).

An echo in this context just means whether if you send a simple message to a remote computer if you hear back.  (Similar to ping/ICMP message).

EDIT: See Graham Hill's excellent comment below to disable this feature in chrome (In Settings, Under the Hood, uncheck "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google" or similar text.)

```
# whois googleechotest.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

   Domain Name: GOOGLEECHOTEST.COM
   Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
   Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com
   Referral URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
   Name Server: NS1.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS2.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS3.GOOGLE.COM
   Name Server: NS4.GOOGLE.COM
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 21-oct-2011
   Creation Date: 21-oct-2011
   Expiration Date: 21-oct-2013
...

Registrant:
        DNS Admin
        Google Inc.
        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway 
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6502530000 Fax: +1.6502530001

    Domain Name: googleechotest.com

        Registrar Name: Markmonitor.com
        Registrar Whois: whois.markmonitor.com
        Registrar Homepage: http://www.markmonitor.com

    Administrative Contact:
        DNS Admin
        Google Inc.
        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway 
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6502530000 Fax: +1.6502530001
    Technical Contact, Zone Contact:
        DNS Admin
        Google Inc.
        1600 Amphitheatre Parkway 
         Mountain View CA 94043
        US
        dns-admin@google.com +1.6502530000 Fax: +1.6502530001

    Created on..............: 2011-10-21.
    Expires on..............: 2013-10-21.
    Record last updated on..: 2011-10-21.

    Domain servers in listed order:

    ns1.google.com
    ns2.google.com
    ns4.google.com
    ns3.google.com
```

Comment: You should be able to turn this off by choosing Chrome > Preferences…, going to the Under the Hood section, and unchecking "Help make Google Chrome better by automatically sending usage statistics and crash reports to Google."

(Windows and Linux users get to Under the hood via [Wrench menu] > Options)

Google would prefer you leave it on, though, since these diagnostics are especially helpful for Beta, Dev, and Canary channel builds.